Ahlfors' complex analysis proof doubt - Heine-Borel theorem
I am currently reading Ahlfors' complex analysis. I am confused by his proof that a complete, totally bounded metric space $S$ satisfies the Heine-Borel property (by Heine-Borel property we mean any open cover of $S$ has a finite subcover). His proof began by supposing that there exists an open cover of $S$ without a finite subcover. Then by the total boundedness assumption, $S$ can be covered by a finite number of open balls of radius $\varepsilon_1$. He then claimed that, by the assumption that there exists an open cover of $S$ without a finite subcover, one of the $B(x,\varepsilon_1)$ has no finite subcover.
The question is that I don't understand how the statement "if each [$B(x,\varepsilon_1)$] had a finite subcovering, the same would be true of $S$" works. Isn't $B(x,\varepsilon_1)$ covering itself, so $\lbrace B(x,\varepsilon_1) \rbrace$ would be a finite subcover? Can I understand this statement as "if each [$B(x,\varepsilon_1)$] satisfies Heine-Borel property, the same would be true of $S$"?


Your "but" in your "more precise formulation" has no point.  Yes, he starts with one open cover, which is assumed to have no finite subcover.  He then considers a sequence of finite covers to construct a convergent sequence of points which depends on the initial cover.  There's no "but" here.

@BrianMoehring Thanks for your comment! I was overcomplicated about my question. To be exact, I don't understand how the statement "if each [$B(x,\varepsilon_1)$] had a finite subcovering, the same would be true of $S$" works.

For your new question, the claim is that there's some $B(x,\varepsilon_1) \subset S$ which isn't covered by any finite subset of the original cover ${U_\lambda}$ of $S$.

I think you misunderstand that Ahlfors assumes there is an open covering of $S$ without naming the covering or the sets in the covering. So imagine he instead wrote
"Suppose that there exists an open covering ${U_\alpha: \alpha \in A}$ which does not contain any finite subcovering."

One question: in your definition of "${U_\lambda}$ is a cover of $S$" do you assume $\bigcup_\lambda U_\lambda$ is $=S$ or can it be $\subseteq S$?  (Either works, but the language of the proof, and hence the answer, may be a point of confusion if you require $=$)

@BrianMoehring According to the book, it can be $\subseteq S$

Okay.  I've posted an answer.  If there's any further confusion, I can make it more precise, but I've attempted to keep the language at a conversational level.

In short, your most recent edit seems to mix up covers.
We start the proof by assuming there's an open cover $\{U_\lambda\}$ of $S$ with no finite subcover.
Then we find $S$ is covered by finitely many open balls with radius $\varepsilon_1$.  If each of these balls were covered by finitely many $U_\lambda$, then since finitely many finite sets have a finite union, this would yield a finite subcover of $\{U_\lambda\}$ for $S$.
This is the point: there must be some open ball $B(x,\varepsilon_1)$ for which no finite subset of $\{U_\lambda\}$ is a cover of $B(x,\varepsilon_1)$

Thank you so much for you reply. The proof is now more clear to me. However I am a bit worried that $\lbrace U_\lambda \rbrace$ may not really cover every of the $B(x,\varepsilon_1)$, especially when a $B(x,\varepsilon_1)$ lies close to the boundary of $S$, or even centered outside $S$? Here I am considering the complex plane, where I think the balls can really center outside the set. Edit: I found the relevant discussion in the book. Thank you so much!

if each [$B(x,\varepsilon_1)$] satisfies Heine-Borel property, the same would be true of $S$
Assume for a later contradiction that $\mathcal C$ is an open covering of $S$ that has no finite subcover. Let $\varepsilon_1 = \frac{1}{2}.$ First, we observe that for each $x \in S,$ the open covering $\mathcal C$ provides us with an open covering of $B(x,\varepsilon_1),$ namely ${\mathcal C}_x = \{C \cap B(x,\varepsilon_1): \; C \in \mathcal C \}.$ Note that $B(x,\varepsilon_1)$ is NOT necessarily (and "most likely" is NOT) an element of ${\mathcal C}_x.$ Next, because $S$ is totally bounded, there exists a finite subset $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ of $S$ such that $B(x_1,\varepsilon_1) \cup B(x_2,\varepsilon_1) \cup \cdots \cup B(x_n,\varepsilon_1) = S.$ At this point [parenthetical comment: Here we are inserting a short "sub-proof" by contradiction.] notice that if each of the finitely many open balls $B(x_i,\varepsilon_1)$ satisfies the Heine-Borel property, then for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ we can select finitely many elements from ${\mathcal C}_{x_i}$ whose union is $B(x_i,\varepsilon_1),$ and thus obtain finitely many collections of finitely many elements of $\mathcal C$ whose union is the same as the union of these finitely many open balls, and hence finitely many elements of $\mathcal C$ whose union is $S,$ which contradicts our assumption that no finite subcollection of $\mathcal C$ covers $S.$ Therefore [parenthetical comment: Having obtained a contradiction, we now state what our short "sub-proof" by contradiction allows us to claim.], for at least one $x_i$ the open covering ${\mathcal C}_{x_i}$ of $B(x_i,\varepsilon_1)$ does NOT have a finite subcover, and hence at least one of the open balls $B(x_i,\varepsilon_1)$ does NOT satisfy the Heine-Borel property. Now consider $\varepsilon_2 = \frac{1}{2^2}$ as suggested in the proof, arguing in the same way we did for $\varepsilon_1$ (with the totally bounded space $B(x_i,\varepsilon_1)$ replacing the totally bounded space $S).$ And so on, after which we obtain a contradiction (not within any sub-proof), and thus conclude that no such open covering $\mathcal C$ of $S$ exists.
